# Android:how do i retrieve the contact photo,name,number from the address book and display it using a list view

Tags: android

Android:how do i retrieve the contact photo,name,number from the address book and display it using a list view

Answer (score 1):

You should start with the [reference code samples](http://developer.android.com/guide/samples/index.html).

Here's one about a [table view](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/TableLayout3.html).